# How to deal with limit size when reached at AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

We're trying to take huge advantage of *AWS*'s **DynamoDB**'s ***NoSQL*** with ***IoT*** stuff, but we're not sure of what best practices are regarding item length or item insertions.

Flow goes, each device can read environment data, depending on type of data captured, device sends that *"event's"* `JSON` message to **IoT** *broker*, then to a **Lambda** function in order to map that payload, process it and write to **DynamoDB** table.

Then, there's one table per type of event captured, and an item for each event message received from devices.
But we've come to realize that that's just another pseudo-relational approach.

Read the docs, and thought about only one table as best practice, and one item per device growing in it's inside, with an array of those `JSON` events classified by the key's name.

Something like:

```
    {
        "partition":"<str_an_id>"",
        "range":<uint_maybe_a_timestamp>,
        "event_soil":[
            {<<object with variable length #0},
            {<<object with variable length #1}
            ...
            {<<object with variable length #n}
        ],
        "event_humidity":[
            {<<object with variable length #0},
            {<<object with variable length #1}
            ...
            {<<object with variable length #n}
        ],
        "event_light":[
            {<<object with variable length #0},
            {<<object with variable length #1}
            ...
            {<<object with variable length #n}
        ],
        "event_temperature":[
            {<<object with variable length #0},
            {<<object with variable length #1}
            ...
            {<<object with variable length #n}
        ]
    }
```

Currently we have two devices, so we're expecting to have two items growing with the `JSON` payload from devices. But, at some point, memory threshold is reached, and a `400` error code from **DynamoDB** raises.

Is this approach right? Or totally wrong?

Is there any approach for knowing when to reach that limit?  Like, some sort of pagination or something?

It's hard to bring the math of calculating item size because the `JSON` objects currently vary in length, and may vary in the future.

Also we've come to think about creating items each one or two months (theoretically since we accelerate devices) per device. But, not sure.

Comment: Error code `400` is not related to Memory. It is raised when access is denied.

Comment: `Item size to update has exceeded the maximum allowed size (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: AKQESTATUSCODEFROMDYNAMODBEZ)`

Comment: The max item size is 400KB, which is pretty large. Typically at that size you're dealing with a JSON file, not an item, and can persist it to S3. If you really need such large items then perhaps partition them further along event type, e.g. partition key could be uuid-soil, uuid-humidity.

Comment: Indeed @jamod, and was considering that option, but placed bet at using properly NoSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and one item per device growing in it's inside, with an array of those JSON events classified by the key's name.

If I'm understanding the above, and the code sample...

I'd say you're doing it all wrong.  Repeatedly updating a few records is not a good idea.  Besides running out of space in the item, which you seem to recognize, you'd be paying for twice the I/O's needed (1 read + 1 write).  Not sure where you got the idea from..

For IoT devices, seems like you're dealing with time series data, thus be sure to understand [Best Practices for Handling Time-Series Data in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html)

Perhaps that's overkill with only two devices...but assuming you're going to scale that up considerably...

My first pass would be Partition-Key: "deviceName#date", sort key: "time"

"date" in this case could be a complete date, YYYY-MM-DD, or just YYYY-MM, or even YYYY.  Moving the left over date parts to the sort key.  All depends on how much data you're expecting.  The thing to consider is that a given partition (key) can only store 10GB of data.

If you can limit the data retention to less than 10GB a device, I'd just use device as the partition key, moving the date to the sort-key.

**Edit**
Key points

1. Understand how much data will be generated (written)
2. Understand how your app will present that data to the user(s)
3. A partition provides 10GB of data storage and 3000 RCU/1000 WCU
4. You can only Query() a given partition.  (PartitionKey == "Something")

2 is really important, assuming you select a given period (last 24hrs, last week, ect) are you going to be working with all events for a given device, all events of a certain type, all events for all devices, or ....

Not that you can't do all the above, but what's the primary access?

"Give me all the data, for all time" every time would be Scan()...certainly not a cost effective access method.

Comment: Ok, It suggests to create a new table per time series completion, let's say, like a year of working or so. But it becomes confusing, since the recommendation for NoSQL is to leverage the number of tables and crossed references among them using the benefits of the NoSQL. So, we're  currently analyzing your first pass suggested at one table. it becomes tricky at selecting which sort key format can be appropiate for this scenario.

Comment: @jon "one table" doesn't always mean a single physical table...rather think of it as a single logical table;  no "relations" between physical tables.  In the case of time-series data, multiple physical tables is simply a cost-savings measure given the anticipated workload of the scenario.  If a single physical table works for you, by all means, go that route.

Comment: Creating a new table per interval is helpful if you so you can just drop old tables instead of deleting the contents. The TTL feature allows you to delete old record without consuming write capacity so the rolling tables are less necessary now.

Comment: @Charles, I've reading the _AWS_ docs, watching design tutorials on _Youtube_ of _AWS_. And for those cases, they indeed recommend time series tables. At [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/design-patterns-for-high-volume-time-series-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/] is explained that, despite an anti-pattern of NoSQL, it's cost saving. So, that  arised a question. Is it recommended to have one table per type of event, and let's say, have a partition key per device per year? In order to avoid the multi-table? Or a table per event per year  with the device uuid as partition key?

Comment: @cementblocks But what about, when management folks want reports of lifetime of the system data things? Data might be served well, fast, and cost-savvy, but all the rest gone.

Comment: @jon there's no one right answer, if you need to keep data available forever, then do so.  Either in DDB, or something else, S3 for instance.

Comment: Aight then, @jamod, @Charles, I'll give a it a shot with the answers and suggestions given. With pk: `uuid-year` and sk: <uint_timestamp>, see how it fits, maybe some mixes of Hierarchical pattern and Time Series (w/o the creation of tables). Thanks for your time.